# Various ways of substitution in Vim

Tags: vim, macros, substitution

How would you do to turn this

```
Dragon.Ball.026.C'est.la.finale.!!.Kame.hame.ha.mkv
Dragon.Ball.027.Goku...Le.moment.le.plus.critique.mkv
Dragon.Ball.028.Impact.!!.La.puissance.contre.la.puissance.mkv
Dragon.Ball.029.A.nouveau,.l'aventure..Le.lac.errant.mkv
Dragon.Ball.030.Pilaf.et.l'armée.mystérieuse.mkv
```

into this

```
Dragon.Ball.026.mkv
Dragon.Ball.027.mkv
Dragon.Ball.028.mkv
Dragon.Ball.029.mkv
Dragon.Ball.030.mkv
```

I succeeded with difficulty with a macro, but there may be a simple way ?
(substitution, block mode, macro or anything else..)

It's for my personal knowledge,

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remember parts of a match with capture groups: `\(` and `\)`. So match and
remember everything up to the last digit `\d`, plus the rest of the line `.*`
(but don't remember this part), and use `\1` to put back the remembered part of
the line, and manually add the extension `.mkv`:

```
:%s/\(.*\d\).*/\1.mkv
```

See `:help pattern-searches`, `:help pattern-atoms` and in particular `:help \(`

##### Note

You could also remember the extension with a second capture group and add it
back like with `\2`:

```
:%s/\(.*\d\).*\(\.mkv\)/\1\2
```

Comment: Great explanation, thanks a lot also for the tips with the :help

Comment: @dp403aan You're welcome - please consider upvoting any answers that were helpful and you can also mark your favourite answer as 'accepted' (the green tick) if you felt it answered your question. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

A slightly shorter solution

```
:%s/\d\.\zs.*\.//
```

That is, find digit followed by dot; then match and delete everything until (and including) the last dot. The regex is guaranteed to work right as the "star" operator is greedy.

Comment: Very interesting too, didn't know about `\zs`, need to go further for this. Thanks a lot.